# JavaScript or jQuery to auto check next checkboxes - Office365

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, office365

I have the checkboxes list auto updated from the server side on scroll down.  I want to know if it is possible to auto check the next 3 checkboxes in the list after the checkbox is checked.

for example  i  have 5 checkboxes in list

```
<input type="checkbox" name = "c1" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c2"  value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c3" value="3"/>    
<input type="checkbox" name = "c4" value="4"/>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c5"  value="5"/>
```

So when checkbox 2 is clicked then the next 3 are auto checked--is that possible?

I searched and played with a checkbox library that I found on Github, but it provides just range selection of checkboxes.

http://rmariuzzo.github.io/checkboxes.js/#limit-max-number-of-checked-checkboxes

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/mcw54bp0/)

Comment: i tried my javascript code is little long , so pasting it here will be no good , will make question long , or should i paste it

Comment: ok i will make jsfiddle ,

Comment: jsfiddle :: https://jsfiddle.net/mcw54bp0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `nextAll` with `:lt(3)` to get the next 3.

```js
$('[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
  
  $(this).nextAll('[type="checkbox"]:lt(3)').prop('checked', this.checked);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name = "c1" value="1"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c2"  value="2"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c3" value="3"/><br>    
<input type="checkbox" name = "c4" value="4"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c5"  value="5"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c6"  value="6"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c7"  value="7"/><br>
<input type="checkbox" name = "c8"  value="8"/><br>
```

> **COMMENT** it work on normal checkboxes however i wonder why it not works on
>   office365 checkboxes

office365 checkboxes are in div containers. This means you need to go up a level, then nextAll, then find the checkbox inside the 3 containers.

```js
$('.f-choice input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().nextAll('.f-choice:lt(3)').find('[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>
  office 365 checkboxes
</p>
<div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
  <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"
  aria-invalid="false">
  <label for="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"></label>
</div>
<div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
  <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"
  aria-invalid="false">
  <label for="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"></label>
</div>
<div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
  <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"
  aria-invalid="false">
  <label for="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"></label>
</div>
<div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
  <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"
  aria-invalid="false">
  <label for="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"></label>
</div>
<div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
  <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"
  aria-invalid="false">
  <label for="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"></label>
</div>
<div class="ms-ChoiceField f-choice" data-hint="Users" data-value="SelectItem">
  <input id="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-input dataListField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" ng-change="UpdatedSelectedUsers(item)" tabindex="0" aria-checked="false"
  aria-invalid="false">
  <label for="selectUser_07c4ab10-4ad0-44d1-9d65-aeee70be20a6" class="ms-ChoiceField-field"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: it work  on normal checkboxes however i wonder why it not works on office365 checkboxes , can you please check :: https://jsfiddle.net/mmzth076/2/

Comment: hmmm classes need to be added when in sub div , what if no class it top div :(  can you please check fiddle :: https://jsfiddle.net/mmzth076/3/

Comment: still no success :( i wonder i need to add classes till root or what . :: can you please check full page dump  .  thanks   ::  http://jsbin.com/cimatunipe/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to check the boxes ahead of the current one, and assuming you set their ID tags:

```
document.getElementById('c2').setAttribute('onclick', 'checkNextThree()');
function checkNextThree(){
    document.getElementById('c3').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    document.getElementById('c4').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
    document.getElementById('c5').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
}
```

When the checkbox c2 is activated, it sets the next three checkboxes to be checked. Some slight edit may be needed if you need to do the next threee checkboxes no matter which is clicked, but there's the concept.